# Add floating button on a CardView and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-cardview, androiddesignsupport

I have this problem to accommodate my floating button, and I do not understand why it does not work.
I would appreciate your response since I can not find the reason why this is happening, one more detail when scrolling or reloading the fragment some of the floating buttons will be accommodated.
And sorry for my English.

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/mRequestCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/vDivisor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/colorGreen" />
                   ...

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPurple"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_route_direction"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/mRequestCard"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="right|end|bottom" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is my RecyclerView Which is inflated in a fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.test.HistorialFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mRecyclerRequest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is my fragment, where I show the RecyclerView

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.test.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should try in floating button android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"

Answer (score 0):

you should try `RelativeLayout` like this

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/activity_corner"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_margin">
        <!--your cardview item here-->
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

for your `RecyclerView` item

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/mRequestCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/vDivisor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorGreen" />
                ...

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/mRequestCard"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|end|bottom" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this use `RelativeLayout`  and make your    `FloatingActionButton` **property**  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` **and**
        `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` like below code

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlack"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/activity_corner"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_margin">


 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```